# OrmLite и Gson проблемы с ForeignCollection

Tags: java, android, база-данных, json

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с проблемой Ormlite-а и Gson-а, Gson не может работать с ForeignCollection. Как вы решили эту проблему?

Мой класс, который нужно превратить в json

```
public class Building {

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.INTEGER, columnName = "id", generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING, columnName = "name")
    private String address;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
    private ForeignCollection<Person> persons;

}  


public class Person {

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.INTEGER, columnName = "id",
                    generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING, columnName = "name")
    private String name;

    @DatabaseField (foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    public Building building;

}
```

Comment: а в чем заключается то проблема?, после сериализации persons == null?

Comment: добавьте пустой конструктор в класс person.  public person (){} и аналогичное сделайте  в Building